# Openshift CLI - update Application with template and oc new-app

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, openshift, openshift-client-tools, build-pipeline

I am currently building and deploying an Application with a template using

```
oc new-app -f ./openshift/template.yaml
```

I am using a template and not separate Deployment-, Build-, etc. configs because I also want to be able to pass parameters like

```
oc new-app -f ./openshift/template.yaml --p DATABASE_PW=PW
```

To my knowledge this is not possible using

```
oc create -f ./openshift/deploymentconfig.yaml --p SOME_PARAM=TEST
```

Now I have also integrated this is in a Build Pipeline with Jenkins. My problem is now this. This all works fine on the first deployment, but it will not work for a redployment. I can either just rebuild the app  with Jenkins like

```
oc start-build my-app
```

But this will cause that changes is my Template will not be considered. I also cannot use new-app as it does not replace existing configs producing an error similar to this

```
--> Creating resources ...
    error: services "my-app" already exists
    ....
--> Failed
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? Maybe something like a `new-app replace` command where all the configs are being replaced? I am currently solving this by killing the app completely using a shell file and then bringing it up again; but that will always cause a downtime of a few minutes which really bothers me.

Comment: Try ``oc process -f openshift/template.yaml --param DATABASE_PW=PW | oc apply -f -``.

Comment: Awesome. This is exaclty what I needed. Can be so simple if you know how. I saw it works also for the creation so i wont even need oc new-app anymore. Do you want to write it down as answer or shall I?

Comment: You can also store your parameters in a file, and then pass the file with `--param-file=`, which is nice when you start accumulating more and more parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) pointed out the best way to solve this is to use

```
oc process -f openshift/template.yaml -p PARAM1=VALUE1 -p PARAM2=VALUE2
```

to first fill your template with your parameters. Then pipe the command to oc apply to apply it to the application which will leave you with the following command

```
oc process -f openshift/template.yaml -p PARAM1=VALUE1 -p PARAM2=VALUE2 | oc apply -f -
```

This will create or update all your configs. It will also check which configs have been changed.

If you want to start the build directly afterwards use

```
oc start-build my-app
```

Comment: Is there a way to skip `oc new-app` and instantiate an application directly with `oc process | oc apply`?

Comment: using oc apply on resources that were created via new-app with a template gives the warning message: "oc apply should be used on resource created by either oc create --save-config or oc apply". This makes me think there must be something different in mind for resources created from templates - or that maybe oc create/oc apply are preferred over using oc new-app.

Answer (score 0):

To update a template parameter in a running pod which was started from a template YAML file (i.e. with `oc create -f ./$tmpl_name.yaml`):

```
# delete existing dc (leaving svc & route)
# (here dc and template are named the same: $tmpl_name)
oc delete dc $tmpl_name
    
# update template parameter (notice template was not deleted)
oc process $tmpl_name -p $PARAM_NAME=$PARAM_VALUE | oc create -f -
```